# Why can't Rserve run?

Tags: r, qliksense, rserve

I want to use R on Qlik, and I began by following this process : https://community.qlik.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/18785-102-1-25264/Installing%20R%20with%20Qlik%20Sense.pdf

I installed R (with the specific install path, but R-3.4.4), and Qlik (September 2018 version).

Then I followed the different steps, until the 6th.

There, when I run Rserve.exe, I get an error : "Fatal error: unable to open the base package".

However I checked that the base package is well installed.

I didn't find where does it come from.

-> Is it a problem of R or Qlik version ?

-> Or is there someting else to take care of ?

Thank you very much for your advice !

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer :

- creating an environment variable
- calling it R_HOME
- value : the path to R (C:\R\R-3.4.4)